# Understanding the block coverage measures of Block Testing

Tags: unit-testing, testing, block

I am trying to understand Block Testing using the book: "How we test software at Microsoft" by Alen Page, Ken Johnston, Bj Rollison. On page 118 and 119 of the book I am given two block function examples.

I have provided pictures of these functions:

[Block Example 1](http://i76.photobucket.com/albums/j17/urzur/Public/Block1.jpg)

[Block Example 2](http://i76.photobucket.com/albums/j17/urzur/Public/Block2.jpg)

The book says that block coverage measures the number of contiguous groups of statements unbound by branches. I believe I am not understanding this.

Can someone explain why

```
int x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;
if (condition)
```

is considered 1 block in `BlockExample1` and

```
int x = 0, y = 0, z = 0;
if (condition 1 && condition2)
```

is considered 4 Blocks in `BlockExample2`?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simplification of the code in question:

```
int x = 0;
if (c1 && c2)
{
    x = 1;
}
```

Because of the potential for short-circuiting (when `c1` if false), that code is equivalent to the following:

```
int x = 0;        > #1                       > #5
if (c1)           |                          |
{                                  > #4      |
    if (c2)       > #2             |         |
    {                     > #3     |         |
        x = 1             |        |         |
    }                     |        |         |
}                                  |         |
```

By contrast, this code has fewer blocks:

```
int x = 0;        > #1        > #3
if (c1)           |           |
{                     > #2    |
    x = 1             |       |
}                     |       |
```

Comment: There is one thing I am still not getting. If I compare Block Example 2 Function provided above and do not consider the return statement it should equal 5 blocks according to your explanation. Instead, the book states there are 6 blocks. Can you also elaborate on the area of coverage of >#2 ? It seems to be clear on the code with fewer code but on the short-circuit example I can't determine what block it covers

Comment: @Angel I tried to mimic the authors' block counting methods, but I don't fully understand them.